# How do you install rbindlist on R v 3.3.3

Tags: r, geolocation, rbind, rscript

> install.packages("rbindlist")
>           Warning in install.packages :package ‘rbindlist’ is not available (for R 
>           version 3.3.3)

I'm working with R version 3.3.3 and attempting to install the rbindist package, but it is not available on this version. I know some people are able to download it through installing other packages first. I was wondering if anyone knew what code to run to get rbindlist?

I'm geomapping locations of twitter users and have not been able to do so without rbindlist

Comment: are you referring to `rbindlist` function in `data.table` package?

Comment: On CRAN is no package `rbindlist` https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/available_packages_by_name.html#available-packages-R Is the package from another source?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`rbindlist` is a function in the [data.table](https://cran.r-project.org/package=data.table) package. You can install that package first and call the function directly. For example,

```
## Install data.table package
install.packages("data.table")

## Load data.table package
library(data.table)

## Call rbindlist function
rbindlist(
  list(
    data.table(A = 1:3, B = letters[1:3]),
    data.table(A = 4:5, B = letters[4:5])
  )
)
```